# GET more than one object from JSON using Mono

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Looking at this code:

```
@Service
public class WebService {        
    
    public WebService() {
                        
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .build();
    }
        
    public Mono<Person> searchById(String id) {
        return webClient.get().uri("/v3/"+ id).retrieve().bodyToMono(Person.class);             
    }
}
```

And this:

```
WebService ws = new WebService();
Mono<Person> version = ws.searchById("1");
System.out.println(version.toProcessor().block());
```

This code works well in getting one person object from a JSON, however I wanted a method to return **more than one person** from a JSON like so:

`public Mono<List<Person>>` or `public Mono<Person[]>`

And I can't seem to make it work. I've tried what I found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-json-list#mapping-a-list-of-json-objects), but I don't understand what they are doing here:

```
return Arrays.stream(objects)
    .map(object -> mapper.convertValue(object, Reader.class))
    .map(Reader::getFavouriteBook)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And in my case I want to have a list of objects `Person` on my main function, not just part of the object like in their case, where they use `Reader::getFavouriteBook` to apparently map a Book.

Comment: Did you try changing to `bodyToMono(Person[].class)`

Comment: If I implement exactly like I did but with [], it just prints garbage like so: [project.xpto.mapping.Person;@3d764641

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString(version.toProcessor().block())` if toString is overridden or print inside a loop.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much man!

Comment: @aksappy Btw, If I wanted to do operations on the object before printing it out, how should I do it? What I mean is, instead of this:

`Mono<Person> version = ws.searchById("1");
System.out.println(version.toProcessor().block());`

Something like this:

`> Mono<Person> version = ws.searchById("1");
> //transfrom version into an object of Person instead of Mono<Person> called newVersion
> //print out new object after operations with Person object
> System.out.println(version.toProcessor().block());`

Comment: Please update the question when you get sometime, I have converted the comment to an answer so that it is readable and comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting this to an answer, for better readability.

WebClient can convert the response body into a mono of array. So, instead of performing `bodyToMono(Person.class)` we can do `bodyToMono(Person[].class)`.

Now the resulting Mono is a `Mono<Person[]>`. You can then perform `map`, `subscribe` or `flatMap` as you wish (one or many times) to chain actions. Once all the actions are chained, you can then call `block` to wait till all the actions are executed and get back the result (or an error).

See this [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) to know more about all the supported methods on Mono.

**Note** - Using block in a reactive application is not recommended.

**EDIT**

Here is an example on how a `Mono<Person>` is converted to a `Mono<PersonDTO>`

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();

        Mono<Person> personMono = Mono.just(person);
        Mono<PersonDTO> personDTOMono = personMono.map(p -> {
            PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO();
            dto.setName(p.name);
            dto.setVersion(p.version);
            return dto;
        }).delayElement(Duration.of(1000L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
        System.out.println("Waiting for 1000 millis");
        System.out.println("personDTOMono = " + personDTOMono.block());
    }

}

class Person {
    int version = 10;
    String name = "test";
}

class PersonDTO {
    private int version;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersonDTO{" +
                "version=" + version +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, i'm trying to use map but with no success. From reading I found out, map is to "Transform the item emitted by this {@link Mono} by applying a synchronous function to it". Great, so I want to transform the Mono<Person> to Mono<PersonDTO> so I can insert in the database after changing it, lets assume.

Initial code:
`Mono<Person> version = ws.searchById("1");`

Transforming:
`Mono<PersonDTO> versionDTO = version.map(id -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()).map(name -> ...)`

How can I do something like  `version.getName()` after `name->` ?

Comment: version.map will give you the Person object, and on that apply the conversions to PersonDTO. UUID can be assigned directly to the DTO object and does not need chaining.

Comment: Sorry to ask but can you give me an example of a transformation from Mono<Person> to Person using map or flatMap? Tried a lot of different things , can't make it work.

Comment: I have added a code example (with some obvious assumptions) which uses a map to convert Person to PersonDTO. Hope it helps and pleasure is all mine.